# How to change default product sort order in OpenCart

Tags: php, sorting, opencart

I want to change the default sort order in my opencart store to increasing by price but i cant figure out how. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do mean? The cheaper price to be seen first and the more expensive one to come last? Which page do you want to change? category?

Comment: exactly. I want it to be the cheapest first and most expensive last. On the category page. On the left side theres a sort option, and i want the default one to be sort by price (increasing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. You have to edit the following file, assuming you want to change the sort order of the category page:

```
catalog/controller/product/category.php
```

then go down several lines (for my file it is line 21, for you, it might differ), probably the second condition of your file (which is in method `index()`), find the following code:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }
```

And replace it with this:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.price';
        }
```

Note that with the above change, you are still able change the sort order from the page itself, it just changes the default `sort_order`.

Comment: H i replaced it, this is the end of the sql now: NOW())) ORDER BY ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special"; but it didnt seem to do the trick

Comment: unfortunately no. i cleared my cache too, but it still orders it by priority

Comment: I have updated the answer, it works (tested). Undo your previous change and then apply the above change. if it works, don't forget accepting it as an answer.

Comment: not working in version 2.x,
for version 2.x I had to make changes in file `system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/product/category.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 1.5.x to 1.5.6 then make sure you have to change at 
catalog/model/catalog/product.php
then search for 
    **} else { $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order"; }**
may be on line number 195/196
and replace with 
    **} else { $sql .= " ORDER BY p.price"; }**
make sure you have already change above code 
i hope that will works
thanks